# How do I configure existing Power Controls widget in Android?

Tags: app-widgets, cyanogenmod

I've added stock Power Controls widget to the home screen of my Android 2.3 (Cyanogenmod).
While being installed it displayed its settings screen.

Now I'm unable to reconfigure the widget. The only option I have is to remove and add the widget to home screen, so that the settings screen will reappear.

Is there any place where I can configure the Power Controls widget without re-adding it?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I have found.  Looks like you only get that one opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used CyanogenMod for a few days before reverting back to SamdroidMod since CM on Spica is too unstable for daily use. But I think I remembered seeing some settings that seems related to Power Widget on "Settings > CyanogenMod Settings".

Comment: Under Settings > CyanogenMod Settings > Interface Settings there is an option for the notification shade power widget but not for the regular home screen widget